# Do you have a good Wit recipe?

Tags: recipe, all-grain

I'm looking to do an all grain Witbier as one of my first AG brews. Bell's Winter White is a commercial example that I like, although I'm not necessarily looking to clone it.

Comment: I don't. I don't even know if I'm made a wit before.

Comment: This question is a little too broad.

Comment: Cleaning up tags: Changed recipes -> recipe

Answer (score 3):

Might be what you are looking for.

[Killer Bee Belgian Wit](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f71/killer-bee-belgian-wit-73278/)

I hope I am not violating a community covenant on linking to outside sites.  Just trying to help.

Comment: Nope, link away.